# lateinit fields become optional in Realm (without any changes in the object)

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

At some pint after updating my App realm crashes with error that

> migration is needed for lateinit fields as they become optional

This is how those fields are declared

```
    @PrimaryKey
    lateinit var uuid: String
    lateinit var date: String
```

No changes were made in the realm structure and realm version hasn't been updated.
Realm version used `"io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:6.1.0"`

Answer (score 2):

After long hours of testing, I have found out that this error happens after I have updated `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin` to version **1.4.20**.
It looks like there are some changes in bytecode generation that had caused different interpretation of `lateinit` fields by Realm.
There is an open issue on [Github](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/7226).  Currently as a workaround, we can mark those fields as `@Required`